# How to refresh drop down menu after button click in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have the following php and html so a user can select the date & time format they wish to use and save it. Everything works fine except after the changes are made the dropdown box still shows the old setting. To see the new setting selected in the dropdown box I have to refresh the page. Is there a way for me to refresh/reload the dropdown after the "Save Time Settings" button is clicked?

Thanks for your help.

```html
<?php
$date1 = date('m-d-Y | h:i A'); //12hr format
$date2 = date('m-d-Y | H:i'); //24hr format
$date3 = date('Y-m-d | h:i A'); //12hr format
$date4 = date('Y-m-d | H:i'); //24hr format
$date5 = date('d-m-Y | h:i A'); //12hr format
$date6 = date('d-m-Y | H:i'); //24hr format

//Read time setting from INI
$lines_array = file("modules/evolution/evolution.ini");
$search_string = "timesettings";

foreach($lines_array as $line) {
    if(strpos($line, $search_string) !== false) {
       list(, $new_str) = explode("=", $line);
          $new_str = trim($new_str); //This line removes the spaces before and after.
    }
}

$inicurrenttime = $new_str;

function MDY12HR() {
    $timehtml = file_get_contents('modules/evolution/time/MDY12HR/top.html');
    $tophtml = 'themes/Evolution/top.html';

    file_put_contents($tophtml, $timehtml);
}

function MDY24HR() {
    $timehtml = file_get_contents('modules/evolution/time/MDY24HR/top.html');
    $tophtml = 'themes/Evolution/top.html';

    file_put_contents($tophtml, $timehtml);
}

function YMD12HR() {
    $timehtml = file_get_contents('modules/evolution/time/YMD12HR/top.html');
    $tophtml = 'themes/Evolution/top.html';

    file_put_contents($tophtml, $timehtml);
}

function YMD24HR() {
    $timehtml = file_get_contents('modules/evolution/time/YMD24HR/top.html');
    $tophtml = 'themes/Evolution/top.html';

    file_put_contents($tophtml, $timehtml);
}

function DMY12HR() {
    $timehtml = file_get_contents('modules/evolution/time/DMY12HR/top.html');
    $tophtml = 'themes/Evolution/top.html';

    file_put_contents($tophtml, $timehtml);
}

function DMY24HR() {
    $timehtml = file_get_contents('modules/evolution/time/DMY24HR/top.html');
    $tophtml = 'themes/Evolution/top.html';

    file_put_contents($tophtml, $timehtml);
}

//code to change time settings
if(isset($_REQUEST['submittime'])){
   $dropdownvalue=$_POST['timesetting']; 
  
if($dropdownvalue == "MDY12HR"){
 $func = 'MDY12HR';
 $func();        
}

if($dropdownvalue == "MDY24HR"){
 $func = 'MDY24HR';
 $func();        
}
if($dropdownvalue == "YMD12HR"){
 $func = 'YMD12HR';
 $func();        
}
if($dropdownvalue == "YMD24HR"){
 $func = 'YMD24HR';
 $func();        
}
if($dropdownvalue == "DMY12HR"){
 $func = 'DMY12HR';
 $func();        
}
if($dropdownvalue == "DMY24HR"){
 $func = 'DMY24HR';
 $func();        
}
}

//code to write to ini file
$lines_array = file("modules/evolution/evolution.ini");
$search_string = "timesettings";

foreach($lines_array as $line) {
    if(strpos($line, $search_string) !== false) {
       list(, $new_str) = explode("=", $line);
          $new_str = trim($new_str); //This line removes the spaces before and after.
    }
}

$inicurrenttime = $new_str;

if(isset($_REQUEST['submittime'])){
 $arr=glob("modules/evolution/evolution.ini"); //your ini file's path
  $dropdownvalue=$_POST['timesetting']; 
  
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
 $str=file_get_contents($val);
   $str=str_replace($inicurrenttime, $dropdownvalue, $str); 
  file_put_contents($val, $str);
 }
}
?>

<h2>Evolution Theme Time Settings</h2>
<div class="colorbox">
<br>
<label id="steps">Select the date & time setting for the Evolution theme.</label>
<br>
<br>
<form action="home.php?m=evolution" method="post">
<label for="color2">Current Date & Time Setting: </label>
<select name="timesetting" >
<option name="MDY12HR" value="MDY12HR" <?php if($inicurrenttime == "MDY12HR") echo "selected"; ?>>(MM/DD/YYYY | 12HR) Example: <?php echo ($date1) ?></option>
<option name="MDY24HR" value="MDY24HR" <?php if($inicurrenttime == "MDY24HR") echo "selected"; ?>>(MM/DD/YYYY | 24HR) Example: <?php echo ($date2) ?></option>
<option name="YMD12HR" value="YMD12HR" <?php if($inicurrenttime == "YMD12HR") echo "selected"; ?>>(YYYY/MM/DD | 12HR) Example: <?php echo ($date3) ?></option>
<option name="YMD24HR" value="YMD24HR" <?php if($inicurrenttime == "YMD24HR") echo "selected"; ?>>(YYYY/MM/DD | 24HR) Example: <?php echo ($date4) ?></option>
<option name="DMY12HR" value="DMY12HR" <?php if($inicurrenttime == "DMY12HR") echo "selected"; ?>>(DD/MM/YYYY | 12HR) Example: <?php echo ($date5) ?></option>
<option name="DMY24HR" value="DMY24HR" <?php if($inicurrenttime == "DMY24HR") echo "selected"; ?>>(DD/MM/YYYY | 24HR) Example: <?php echo ($date6) ?></option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submittime" value="Save Time Settings"/>
</form>
<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Update it via JavaScript - PHP has no ability to control the display of the page once loaded.  Load your values via ajax, and then just updated whatever you need in the front-end with JavaScript.  Otherwise a page refresh is required for PHP to build that portion of your page (if that is how you are building it) so the value can be updated.